# parseString undefined in angular 6 using xml2js

Tags: json, xml, angular, typescript, xml2js

I cannot get the xml2js code to work so far using angular 6. I have a service.ts returning xml however when calling xml2js.parseString to convert to json I consistently get an undefined error.

"core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseString' of undefined
 "

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Zid {
  zpid: number;
}
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'text'
};    

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CdataServiceService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  zipID = 'http://APiXml';
  getZipID() {
    return this._http.get(this.zipID, httpOptions)
    .pipe
      (map
        (res => 
          {
            return res
          }
        )
      )
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdataServiceService, Zid } from '../cdata-service.service';
import { xml2js } from 'xml2js';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cgetter',
  templateUrl: './cgetter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cgetter.component.css']
})
export class CgetterComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [];

  constructor(private cds: CdataServiceService) { }

  onKeyCompGet(event:any){
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  _zid :Zid

  getTheComps(){
    this.cds.getZipID()//cdataServiceService.getZipId()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.convertToJson(res);
     })
  }


  public convertToJson(data: string): Object {

    let res;
    console.log(data);

    xml2js.parseString(data, { explicitArray: false }, (error, result) => {

      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      } else {
        res = result;
        console.log(result);
      }

    });

    return res;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have ran the returned xml to an online converter and didn't run into any problems. I have no clue on why the function returns undefined.

Also is there a way to verify all the files in xml2js is being loaded properly?

Comment: `xml2js` is not loaded, as the error states it is undefined. How is that referenced? Is it imported through `package.json`?

Comment: "xml2js": "^0.4.17" - package-lock.json 

this got placed there auto after running 'npm install xml2js'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your import in class `CgetterComponent` to:

```
import xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

Or:

```
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
```

If you examine the [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/lib/xml2js.js) file which is referenced as the `main` file in the project's `package.json`. It exports an object with various properties such as `Builder`, `Parser`, and `parseString`, none of them have the name/identifier `xml2js`. So the [named import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_single_export_from_a_module) you are using of `import { xml2js } from 'xml2js';` is attempting to important a non-existent object property (log `xml2js` in the example I shared to see exported properties), hence the `undefined`.

Another import approach you can take, is using a named import to directly import the `parseString` function you are using. This would look like:

```
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';
```

And then you would simply use it as follows:

```
parseString(data, { explicitArray: false }, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  } else {
    res = result;
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mejj6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of the import/usage in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the issue and now it's working perfectly. I now understand this alot better with how you broke it down.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding!

Comment: I like to highlight that parseString callback take TWO parameters, and instead of having usual result first, and error second, we have the opposite here. I kept getting null value as result, my callback looked like that `e => { console.log(e); // null }`.